# Acquire Power BI Service Access token in Python without client_id

Tags: python, python-3.x, powerbi, adal, azure-ad-msal

I can use the the PowerShell cmdlet MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt to get an access token using (1) username and (2) password parameters inputs. It works perfectly. Note that it doesn't require an client_id parameter:

```
# PowerShell code:

Import-Module MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt

Function authenticate_powerbiserviceaccount($us, $pw)
{
    # Convert plain text pw to secureString
    $pw_secure = $pw | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force

    # Authenticate
    $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($us, $pw_secure)
    Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -Credential $credential

    # Print access token auth_string
    Get-PowerBIAccessToken -AsString
}
```

I've found authentication snippets that use ADAL but they all require a client_id parameter which I don't have and I am not able to get.

```
    # Python code:

    import adal
    authority_url = 'https://login.windows.net/common'
    context = adal.AuthenticationContext(
        authority_url,
        validate_authority=True,
        api_version=None
    )
    
    token = context.acquire_token_with_username_password(
        resource='https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api',
        username=user_string,
        password=pw_string,
        client_id=client_id_string
    )
    access_token = token['accessToken']
```

Is it possible to build a python function that gets the auth_string for a given username and password without the need for a client_id? How does it look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the PowerShell command `Get-PowerBIAccessToken` also uses a `client_id`, it is a well-known application named `Power BI Gateway`, whose `client_id` is `ea0616ba-638b-4df5-95b9-636659ae5121`. To check this, just use fiddler to catch the request of this command.

[image]

> Is it possible to build a python function that gets the auth_string for a given username and password without the need for a client_id?

So answer your question, it is not possible. The ADAL essentially uses the [ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc), the `client_id` is required.

In your case, if you don't have a client app, you just need to use the well-known client_id `ea0616ba-638b-4df5-95b9-636659ae5121` directly in your code, then you can get the token easily.

**Sample:**

```
import adal

AUTHORITY_URL = 'https://login.windows.net/common'
RESOURCE = 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api'
CLIENT_ID = 'ea0616ba-638b-4df5-95b9-636659ae5121'
userid='xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com'
userpassword='xxxx'

context = adal.AuthenticationContext(AUTHORITY_URL,validate_authority=True,api_version=None)
token = context.acquire_token_with_username_password(RESOURCE,userid,userpassword,CLIENT_ID)
access_token = token['accessToken']
print(access_token)
```

[image]